# VBA error 1004, can't find path of folder variable, even though path exists and folder variable holds correct path

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that open text files and imports data from them. It was working one minute, then i passed it to the guy i was writing it for and he got Run-time error 1004: 'Sorry we couldn't find [path], is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?'

Here's my code:

```
Sub OpenTxtFiles()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim xFolder As String
Dim txtFname As String
Dim cellAddr As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim userClass As Integer

xFolder = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
Set rng = Range("E1:I1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False       

            For Each cell In rng
                txtFname = cell.Value   'sets the cell value as txtFname variable
                    'MsgBox txtFname
                    cellAddr = cell.Address    'sets the cell address as cellAddr variable
                    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=xFolder & "\" & txtFname, DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=True
```

ThisWorkbook is saved in the same folder, hence the `xFolder = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path`, so it should work, and if i put `MsgBox xFolder` right after that line, it displays the correct path. I'm very confused. Especially since it was working before i sent it to my colleague.

I tried also replacing the `Application.ThisWorkbook.Path` with a function that asks the user to choose the folder path, but the same error is given.

Can anyone help me understand whats going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are there folder permissions that might be an issue? That your colleague can't access a particular folder?

Comment: `xFolder & "\" & txtFname` .. are you sure xFolder path doesn't contain \ at the end?

Comment: Application.ThisWorkbook.Path doesn't contain an ending \.  Can you build the file and path into a variable first and then use that in OpenText?  Do it on both machines and see if the paths+filenames are exactly the same.

Comment: @QHarr I dont think so as I had things saved to my C (it worked fine, then stopped working), my colleague also was working here and we tried another team drive that we both definitely have access to, but to no avail.

Comment: @PankajJaju I did a test where right at the start after setting xFolder, i added `MsgBox xFolder & 3`, which gave the correct path just with "3" tagged at the end, verifying it doesnt contain a \.

Comment: What happens when you hard code the path?

Comment: @mooseman I have built a new variable `xOpen = xFolder & "\" & txtFname`. However when i ran it i forgot to change the `Workbooks.OpenText...` line to the new variable. But it works anyway with the old way that didnt work previously... Even more confused now. Could this be some sort of bug?

Comment: Gah i think its because i'm running it from a control sheet and i've not specified that it needs to look for the `txtFname` variable on the correct sheet, so its falling down when it finds nothing. Huge facepalm.

Comment: thanks everyone, for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It was an embarrassingly simple thing i forgot:
I setup a separate sheet for control with a button assigned to the macro, so when the path was searching the range to `Set rng` variable, it found nothing on the control sheet and returned the error.
Instead of:

```
Set rng = Range("E1:I1")
```

I needed:

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:I1")
```